# How to show the last 5 posts with image when you upload it from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, gallery

The overall goal is to show the last 5 posts with their image when you upload it to MySQL database. I have 4 files:

- connection.php - hook up to database - works great

  - new_post.php - you can add to the database - work great
  - upload.php - the upload to the database (image and content) - work great
  - index.php - the home-based where everything is displayed * the problematic file*

The main problem I can't figure out is why I see multiple cards in the index.php? 
My guess could be between the while loop and bootstrap conflict. I only have 4 data in mysql.

Here is the index.php:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/720/200/arch" id="banner"/>

<div class="container" id="principal">
    <h1>Bienvenido a mi blog!</h1>
    <a href="new_post.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-add">Agregar post</a>
    <h2>Ultimos 5 posts</h2>
    <div id="card-list">

        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo  '<img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                       <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                         <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                         <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                       </div> ';
            };
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo  '<img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                       <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                         <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                         <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                       </div> ';
            };
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo  '<img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                       <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                         <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                         <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                       </div> ';
            };
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo  '<img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                       <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                         <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                         <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                       </div> ';
            };
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo  '<img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                       <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                         <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                         <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                       </div> ';
            };
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you could help me, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: One while loop is enough. Don't put the same loop 5 times.

Comment: thank you! I did the 5 loops because I can't figure out how to display the cards (title, content, and image) in a horizontal row. Now they are in a separate row vertically. I want them in 4 in a row horizontally. But Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to iterate once, then display each post in a different card.

Your index.php

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

function show_posts() {
    global $conexion;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogtp_1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="imagen/' . $row["imagen_upload"] . '"/>
                <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">' . $row["titulo_del_post"] . '</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">' . $row["contenido_del_post"] . '</p>
                     <a href="ver.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                </div> 
              </div>';
    };
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/720/200/arch" id="banner"/>

<div class="container" id="principal">
    <h1>Bienvenido a mi blog!</h1>
    <a href="new_post.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-add">Agregar post</a>
    <h2>Ultimos 5 posts</h2>
    <div id="card-list">
        <?php show_posts(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YESSSS!!!!!! Thank youuu!!! Its make sense making the while loop into a function! Duh programming 101!! Thank you xanadev!!